# Finding expected value of sample median

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, expectation, sampling

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3$ be a random sample from the standard normal distribution. How do I find the expected value of the sample median?

Comment: **Hint:** Let $x_1<x_2<x_3$. Then the median is $x_2$. What is $E(X_2)$ ?

Comment: Hint: by symmetry, $\mu$.

Comment: I see! Since it's standard normal, would the expected value just be 0?

Comment: @VictorP.: my answer includes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not standard normal at all. The probability density function of  sample median for odd sample size is given here: [look at 4th raw of the table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_distribution#Examples).

For $n=3$ and $k=2$ p.d.f. of second order statistics $X_{(2)}$ equals to 
$$
f_{X_{(2)}}(x)=6 f(x)\Phi(x)(1-\Phi(x))=6f(x)\Phi(x)\Phi(-x),
$$
where $f(x)$ is the p.d.f. of standard normal distribution and $\Phi(x)$ is the cumulative distribution function of standard normal distribution, 
$$
f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}=f(-x),
$$
and the factor $\Phi(x)\Phi(-x)$ is an even function too.

Then the distribution of $X_{(2)}$ is symmetric, but this is **not** a standard normal distribution. The expectation exists and equals to zero, as provided in comments.